# Not able to launch 2nd instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Actually I am getting below error while trying to launch 2nd EC2 instance. I am using AWS free tier. From some blogs I come to know we can launch 20 instance without requesting for limit increase. but I am not able to launch 2nd instance itself. Please let me know if I am missing any other factor which should be considered. I am using Ohio region.

> Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at
>   least 1

Can anyone suggest on this?

Comment: What is the instance type you are requesting, and what is the type you currently have running?

Comment: Quote is per account, are you the only owner of the account or you are user?

Comment: @Mark - I am using t2.micro instance for both running and requesting.

Comment: @Kosa - I am the only owner of the account and I am spining up instance from admin account.

Comment: If you click **Limits** in the EC2 console, how what is the limit shown for `t2.micro`? Also, how many instances are you currently running in that Region? Have you been starting many instances today? (There is a limit of 100 launches or starts of any T2 instance per account, per 24-hour period, per region)

Comment: @John I can see limit on dashboard is 1 for t2.micro. thanks. If anybody can confirm if it's chargable if I request for limit increase.

Comment: @RohitJindal There is no charge for requesting a change of limits. It is very strange that your limit is not the default value of 20.

Comment: Thanks John. I have requested to increase limit.

Comment: It would be good to know the reason for limit 1 instead of 20. Did you submit any support ticket for AWS with this question or on AWS forums?

Comment: @Kosa - thanks for pointing out. i have raised the concern. will post there response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count 20 depends on the instance type. For example if your instance type is p2.xlarge instance then you can run only one EC2 instance.

Please find the list of instance type and limit [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2).

If your instance type is eligible for 20 and you cannot spin up 20 instances, then You can [request for a limit increase](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html).

Comment: @Vijayanth - I am using t2.micro which has limit of 20. But still not able to launch.  Is it chargable when we request for limit increase?